# Warning with bibTeX and IEEEtran

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

When I use Bibtex on my file I've a warning:

`Warning--edition ordinal word "Second Edition" may be too high (or improper) for conversion in FOO`

What can cause this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\cite{FOO}
\end{document}
```

.bib:

```
@book{FOO,
title = "BAR",
author = "John, Smith",
publisher = "some one",
edition = "Second Edition",
address = "Paris",
year = "2015",
}
```

Comment: Page 10 of [BibTeXing](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) indicates edition should just be "Second" or similar.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Problem solved. You could post it as an answer and I'll validate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 10 of [BibTeXing](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) indicates edition should just be "Second" or similar.

> **edition** The edition of a book—for example, “Second”. This should be an ordinal, and should have the first letter capitalized, as shown
>   here; the standard styles convert to lower case when necessary.